# Why is Doctor Psycho considered as one of the deadly foes of Wonder Woman?

Tags: dc, comics, wonder-woman

Among the villains of Wonder Woman, why is Doctor Psycho considered as one of the deadliest of them?

Comment: Considered by whom?

Comment: [Character Biography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_Psycho)

Comment: I don't know about "deadliest", but he's one of the only villains to exist in the Golden, Silver _and_ Bronze Ages, as well as being modernised for New 52. Not many other villains specific to Wonder Woman have been around for as long, besides her main archenemies like Cheetah and Ares.

Comment: Psycho is certainly one of the most *prolific* supervillains that Wonder Woman has faced. He's appeared in over 200 of her comics (either on his own or as part of a troupe of villains) and in every single age; Golden, Silver and Bronze as well as post-Crisis and New 52 incarnations. That being said, he's usually quite ineffective, especially when operating on his own.